# Can't install Jenkins in Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

```
 jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-12-07 13:51:44 IST; 20ms ago
    Process: 8229 ExecStart=/usr/bin/jenkins (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 8229 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 37ms
dpkg: error processing package jenkins (--configure):
 installed jenkins package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jenkins
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: what to do next.
please some one help me

Comment: run this command: ```grep "install\|upgrade" /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "2021-01" > log.dat``` and post the output.